# Menu Dynamic in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I define a function to create a dynamic menu, but it does not work the way I wanted. it displays the parents and son in the same line when I click on the buttons.

Here is the code thank you in advance

```
DataTable tableParent = getData(); 
DataView view = new DataView(tableParent); 
DataTable tablechild = getDataLink();

MenuItem item1 ; 
MenuItem childitems ; 
for (int i = 0; i < tableParent.Rows.Count; i++) 
{ 
    item1 = new MenuItem(); 
    string MenuID1 = tableParent.Rows[i][0].ToString();        
    item1.Text = tableParent.Rows [i][1].ToString();                   
    Menu1.Items.Add (item1); 
    for (int j = 0; j < tablechild.Rows.Count; j++) 
    { 
        childitems = new MenuItem(); 
        string MenuID2 = tablechild.Rows[j][0].ToString ();     
        ChildItems.texte = tablechild.lignes[j][3].ToString();

        if (MenuID1 == MenuID2) 
        {    
            childitems.Text = tablechild.Rows[j][3].ToString (); 

            Menu1.Items[i].ChildItems.Add(childitems); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            ChildItems.NavigateUrl = "~/login.aspx"; 
        }  
    }       
}
```

Comment: `It does not work the way I wanted.`  How do you want it to work?  And have you tried using a [SiteMapDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sitemapdatasource(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: @DavidG - `NavigateUrl = "~/login.aspx"`.  Pretty sure it's asp.net

Comment: Their is no Parent-Son/Daughter terminology in asp.net! it is the Parent-Child :) What error you get? please show your table data too..!

Comment: @user3797625 you should add the solution as an 'Answer' to the  original post! so that others will know in future..for reference!

Comment: I have not changed anything in this !
it works ;-)